# In the main.storyboard the rounded button aren't load

Tags: swift, xcode

I have add the class RoundButton in Swift with the following code:

```
//
//  RoundButton.swift
//

import UIKit

@IBDesignable
class RoundButton: UIButton {

    @IBInspectable var roundButton : Bool = false {
        didSet {
            if roundButton == true {
                layer.cornerRadius = frame.height / 2
            }
        }
    }

    override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
        if roundButton == true {
            layer.cornerRadius = frame.height / 2
        }
    }

}
```

Then I have activate the design in the button properties. In the main.storyboard the buttons are square, but in the build the buttons are round. And it comes this error:

> file:///Users/anonymoushuman/Documents/Apps/Taschenrechner/Taschenrechner/Base.lproj/Main.storyboard: error: IB Designables: Failed to render and update auto layout status for ViewController (BYZ-38-t0r): The bundle “Taschenrechner.app” couldn’t be loaded because its executable couldn’t be located.

[image: Img]

Comment: What you have works for me. Maybe clean & re-build project?

Comment: Wouldn't the buttons in the Stroyboard have to be round as well, it would be easier if they were, since you can see the design faster that way.

Comment: Yes, its working in my Storyboard [Xcode 12.5.1]

Comment: Ok, I have the same version [Xcode 12.5.1], but with me its wrong. Do you have a idea, how I can fix the problem? I restarted the program several times and also my Computer.

Comment: @anonymoushuman Hi, do you manage to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your code works normally.
I also have the same version [Xcode 12.5.1].

[image]
[image]

I searched for the errors you experienced, and I think it would be good to refer to the links.

- https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/665826

I don't know what caused the error, but let me suggest another way. 
This code can also achieve the same results you want to achieve.

```
import UIKit

extension UIButton {
    
    func makeCircle() {
       self.layer.masksToBounds = true
       self.layer.cornerRadius = self.frame.width / 2
    }
 }
```

***result***

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is the extension I wrote. If you want to make a circle, not an ellipse, you can write `button.makeRounded(nil)`. The caution here is that when you make a circle, the vertical and horizontal heights must be equal and the values must be specified.

```swift
extension UIButton {
    
    func makeRounded(cornerRadius : CGFloat?) {
        
        if let cornerRadius_ = cornerRadius {
            self.layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius_
        }  else {
            self.layer.cornerRadius = self.layer.frame.height / 2
        }
        
        self.layer.masksToBounds = true
    }
```